# Auth0 posee api masiva para creacion de usuario?

Tags: nestjs, auth0

Estoy buscando una api para migrar usuarios de mi base de datos a auth0. Tengo muchos usuarios en mi base de datos y necesito pasarlos a auth0 mediante alguna api que me responda con todo los id que les asigna auth0. Alguien sabe si posee una api asi?

Comment: https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/user-migration/configure-automatic-migration-from-your-database